# Personal Access Token not being accepted/recognised when cloning repo on Mac

Tags: github, token, github-api

Beginner developer here.  I created a Personal Access Token (PAT) on Github so that I could clone a repo for local access.  When terminal asks for credentials and I enter my PAT I get the error message below, which I interpret as terminal not recognising the token I entered as a PAT (ie terminal thinks I'm entering a standard password)

> remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13,
> 2021. Please use a personal access token instead. remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/
> for more information. fatal: Authentication failed for
> 'https://github.com/async-labs/builderbook.git./'

Answers to similar questions posted on Stack Overflow suggest updating keychain access with the PAT.  This seems to be successful for many, judging by the upvotes and thankful comments.  I've done this but am still getting the same error message.

I've verified the PAT that I'm copying into terminal is the same as the one served up by Github.

There was a suggestion that SAML SSO's may need to go through an additional process but that seems to be for enterprise account and mine is a personal account.

I'm using macOS Big Sur version 11.6

Answer (score 0):

Urghhh.  So, just reboot the computer (once you've updated your keychain) and it should work.